# vb.net validation

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am having a text box whose text should always be an integer.
How do I validate it ?
Is using ASCII is the right method ? Else is there any other method available ?

Comment: More details needed.  What framework / kind of code is this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rebecca more info is required. Some things that come to mind would be regular expressions for the data entered, an AJAX extended textbox filter that limits the text entered to numbers only, validation on the text entered, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Given the data presented in the question, one easy way you could use is use either Integer.Parse or Integer.TryParse.  The second option is probably better since you do not need a Try/Catch block.  If it fails then you can handle it with a message or whatever you need the user to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this Method..Declare this Method Globally

```
Public Sub NumberValidation(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the Keypress event of Corresponding textbox, You must give Event e as an Argument for this Method..

Ex:   NumberValidation(e) this Will Help You